# Have access to table and function, but not the table within the function

Tags: postgresql

I ran into a peculiar problem with my database that I haven't been able to solve since yesterday.

So I created a user that has access to the function "write_match_history()" and access to the table "match_history," and I can use this user to query match history as well as write to it directly using sql. However, when I try to run "write_match_history," I get the following error:

```
error:  error: permission denied for relation match_history
```

Here are the accesses I've granted to this user:

```
drop OWNED by d_write;
drop user if exists d_write;
create user d_write with encrypted password 'supersecret';
grant execute on function write_match_history(a,b,c,d,e,f) to d_write;
grant usage on schema d to d_write;
grant insert on table d.match_history to d_write;
grant select on table d.match_history to d_write;
grant select on all SEQUENCES in SCHEME d to d_write;
grant insert on all tables in schema d to d_write;
grant select on all talbes in schema d to d_write;
```

These permissions are everything I've tried so far. Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is the owner of the function `write_match_history(a,b,c,d,e,f)`. Do it allow to insert/update on table `match_history`. If not, please try it. I think the problem is here.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking me, but all of the tables and functions were made by the root postgres user. However, I put the functions in the default schema while the tables are in the "d" schema. I'm gonna try moving those, I guess.

Comment: That is only relevant if the function was defined as `SECURITY DEFINER`. But I agree that must be the problem.

Comment: so I tried recreating the functions under the "d" schema, but to no avail. Is there a standard procedure to repair permissions? I never used the "SECURITY DEFINER" function before.

Comment: tried running `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA d TO d_write`, but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Not sure why this worked but this got the job done:

`drop OWNED by d_write;
drop user if exists d_write;
create user d_write with encrypted password 'secret';
grant usage on schema d to d_write;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA d TO d_write;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA d TO d_write;`